# Eclipse SWT browser.evaluate() takes longer to return after each consecutive call

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

When repeatedly calling a javascript function with the swt browser.evaluate() method; it takes longer to return each time. This is not effected by the logic in the javascript function as it also is reproducible with an empty function.

In an Eclipse Viewpart uses the following code to reproduce:

```java
public class BrowserView extends ViewPart {

public static final String ID = "browsertest.views.BrowserView";

public BrowserView() {
}

private Browser browser;
private long stop;
private long start;

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
    browser.setUrl("http://localhost:8555");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Wait
            System.out.println("Start test in 10 seconds.");
            try { Thread.sleep(10000L); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            long duration = 0L;
            // Run java script method 5000 times
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
                browser.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        browser.evaluate("doNothing()");
                        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                });
                duration += (stop - start);

                // Print out average time of each 100 calls
                if(i % 100 == 0){
                    System.out.println("(" + i + "). " + " Time for last 100 calls: " + duration/100);
                    duration = 0L;
                }
            }

            // Do a refresh
            browser.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    browser.refresh();
                }
            });

            // Wait
            System.out.println("Start test in 10 seconds after a refresh.");
            try { Thread.sleep(10000L); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            // Again 1000 
            duration = 0L;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
                browser.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        browser.evaluate("doNothing()");
                        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                });
                duration += (stop - start);

                // Print out average time of each 100 calls
                if(i % 100 == 0){
                    System.out.println("(" + i + "). " + " Time for last 100 calls: " + duration/100);
                    duration = 0L;
                }
            }

        }

    });


    t.start();
}
```

The browser loads the following html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   window.doNothing = function(){
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>Does nothing</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Different variations with numbers of calls and average waits have been tried. Eventually, they all converse to the same conclusion: **The time that evaluate() needs to return increases until the browser is refreshed.**

I tried to pinpoint the problem by going trough the source code. It looks like the delay appears in:

```
org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant.getAutomation()
```

When it is called from

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.execute(String)
```

On line 1220.

Environment:

- Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 build 20160613-1800 as IDE and Target Platform
- swt 3.105.0v20160603-0902
- Windows 10 pro x64 (with Internet Explorer 11)

Questions:

- **Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?**
- **How can I prevent this?**

Comment: Interesting question! Don't really know an answer to this, but I'm curious. How did you discover this? Does this happen in a real-world scenario or did you just stress-test it?

Comment: It happens in a real-world scenario. In our eclipse-rcp application one of the views uses the swt browser. The browser loads one html page including some javascripts. The javascript functions are triggered from within the application and the page is never refreshed. Refreshing the page is even unfeasible in our scenario due to the initialization that is needed. After some time we noticed serious lags in the UI, caused by long running evaluate() methods on the main thread.